# ASP.NET MVC api, Entity Framework and many clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one BIG problem.

I have a WebApi server and method `SetUserStatus`.

There are two entities: `User` and `UserStatus`. They have a one-to-many relationship. Each of them has a `RowVersion` property for optimistic concurrency.

Optimistic concurrency works fine for `User`, when two clients try to modify the same instance of `User`, throwing a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. The problem starts when two or more clients select one user by Id, for exaple, and add new `UserStatus`.

`UserStatus` has an `EndDate` property. It's must filling when new `UserStatus` is added. In my repository I do something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> SetUserStatus(int userId, bool status)
{
    using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var user = await db.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var lastStatus = user.Statuses.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.EndDate.HasValue);

            if (lastStatus != null)
            {
                lastStatus.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
            }

            user.Statuses.Add(new UserStatus { Status = status });

            return await db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So... I have several records with empty `EndDate`. I understand it's because each call of this method has own database context. But I do not known how fix that error. I need only `UserStatus` with empty `EndDate`. I do not want use locks for each call of this method.

Where is my misstake?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are doing this in .Net code. Concurrency is your problem.

Take this scenario:

1. There is one status, without an EndDate
2. First call gets this status
3. Concurrent call gets the same status
4. They both update the first status, and create a new one without an EndDate
5. They both commit
6. You now have 1 status with an EndDate, 2 without.
7. The next call will only update the last one, leaving you with a status without an EndDate.

If you want to have something like this 100% consistent, there are a bunch of options, but the easiest one is probably using a DB trigger or Stored Procedure for this.